# Phonegap, Internet Explorere, and Local Storage or Session Storage

Tags: html, internet-explorer, session, cordova, session-storage

In this link [session storage not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212347/session-storage-not-working-in-ie) it was stated that local storage and session storage will only work with Internet Explorer if the code is accessed as HTTP through a server, but not when opened from the file system with a URL such as  "C:/Users/Mitaksh/Desktop". I have experimented with this, and it seems to be true. 
My question is: If an app is created using Phonegap from code that incorporates local storage or session storage, and that app is run on a device that is using IE, what will be the result? If there is a problem, what can be done to make it work?

Comment: Are you talking about building for Windows Mobile phones? Cordova has support for that OS. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am building an app, and I want to have versions for different phone and tablet devices. My understanding is that a Phonegap created app will make use of the browser used by a particular device. So my question is whether the it is seen by that browser as HTTP or file system URL (for the reason given above)

Comment: PhoneGap works by creating a web view, then opening the local HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files in that web view. You are able to use both localStorage and sessionStorage with PhoneGap.