# Trying to use session storage, getting "Unable to set property 'logon' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, session-storage, web-storage

So, I'm trying to make a simple code for a basic javascript class that will maintain a logon state for a user. The function for them to log on is as follows

```
function userLogon() {
  sessionStorage.logon = "false";
  var name = document.getElementById('userName').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  if (name == "user" && password == "pass") {
    **sessionStorage.logon = "true";**
    alert('Logon successful!');
    window.location = "home.html";
  }

  else {
    alert('Invalid Logon attempt!');
    sessionStorage.logon = "false";
  }
}
```

I'm just hard-coding in the username and logon since I don't have any database experience yet, and just for testing purposes. I was talking to my teacher about it, e-mailed him my whole website, and he says it's working just fine for him, so how come it doesn't work on my machine, and it gives me this Unable to set property error on the bolded line...

I'm running IE 10.0.11 on Windows 8, and ran a script that checks for session storage compatability, and it came back true... So... It should theoretically work? What the heck is the problem?

Comment: sessionStorage is not defined.  It's up to the browser to expose it.  Is local/offline/session storage disabled in your browser preferences?  Also, you say that it fails for you in IE10, and works for your teacher, but didn't say what browser he uses.  Maybe his browser supports it and IE 10 (shocker!) does not.

Comment: I'm not sure what browser version he uses, I've never noticed, but he does most of his testing with IE. I was hunting through my preferences to see if it was, but I didn't see the options anywhere, I'll dig some more.

and as for support, the script I found online to check support for session storage returned true when I ran it in IE 10, so it DOES support it, it's just a matter of finding out why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick search on "sessionStorage IE10" and it showed a stackoverflow question just like this.  The problem is that sessionStorage is only available in IE 10 if the page is accessed via HTTP (in other words, through a web server).  It does not work when opening an HTML page directly from your file system, like "file://C:/Users/blah/test.html"

[session storage not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212347/session-storage-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Well that's annoying, I did a search and didn't come up with anything... My google-fu fails I guess. I did a search on here too. Thanks, guess that would explain it. Maybe for the sake of the project I'll have to use cookies... Though I'd rather not

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a [blog post](http://coding4life.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/sessionstorage-and-localstorage-not-working-in-internet-explorer-10/) about the issue.

Basically Brandon is correct in that Internet Explorer 10 does not support the feature on pages that are loaded from local disk even though there does not seem to be an official documentation on this behaviour.

If you are looking for alternatives, you should definitely check out this stackoverflow post, which lists several solutions:
[HTML5 Local Storage fallback solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692245/html5-local-storage-fallback-solutions)